# How to convert a SSL certificate to an authority?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

How can one convert an SSL cert provided by an authority to another authority, so one can generate "valid" certs for different domains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is to modify the certificate in a way that it contains the ability to be a CA, i.e. set the CA flag to true. Fortunately you cannot simply modify a certificate, because any kind of modification invalidates the signature and thus nobody will trust this certificate anymore. This  is essential because otherwise everybody could just create certificates for sites they don't own and this do man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Ok, I thought so. But my suggestion was, if I might have the private key to "instanciate" an ca from a cert, this would prevent mitm attacks as they didn't know the key. But seems to be valid, that it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, you will have to apply for a new certificate. There are special types of certificates that apply for multiple *previously specified* domains at once.